# Sorting ObservableList<Class> by value in ascending and descending order - JAVAFX

Tags: sorting, javafx, observablelist

I have a Class which has playerName and Score, I have created a ObservableList of this class in my Controller class. Players and scores are added to this array. But the question is how do I sort it according to the score?

```
ObservableList<PlayerScore> playerScores = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
```

This is how it looks so far:

```
//stateACS is a toggle button
if (stateASC.isSelected()) {
    //Sort in asc order by player score
    FXCollections.sort(playerScores);
}else{
    //sort in desc order by player score

}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you use type `Class`. Can you explain this.

Comment: It was just an example, the class real name is PlayerScores. I have updated the question now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just the same way you sort any list by a given criterion: By using a [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), e.g.:

```
// assuming there is a instance method Class.getScore that returns int
// (other implementations for comparator could be used too, of course)
Comparator<Class> comparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Class::getScore); 
if (!stateASC.isSelected()) {
    comparator = comparator.reversed();
}
FXCollections.sort(playerScores, comparator);
```

BTW: `Class` is a poor choice for a class name because of the name clash with `java.lang.Class`.

Answer (score -1):

You can sort the array by implementing a Comparator and then using the sort method with the Comparator instance.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#sort-javafx.collections.ObservableList-java.util.Comparator-)